# add line number after matched pattern in vim

Tags: linux, vim, sed

I have raw sequences and I have to convert it to fasta format.
so reads are like this:

```
CTACGGTGTGCTCTTCCGATCTGACTATG
AGTTGGTGTGCTCTCCCGATCTCGCTCCCTC
GTGAGGTGTGCTCTTCCGATCTCCGGCAGTGTGCT
```

and i want to add > and numbers above each line so finally it should look like:

```
>1
CTACGGTGTGCTCTTCCGATCTGACTATG
>2
AGTTGGTGTGCTCTCCCGATCTCGCTCCCTC
>3
GTGAGGTGTGCTCTTCCGATCTCCGGCAGTGTGCT
```

how can i do in vim? if not vim then can i use sed command?

Answer (score 4):

In vim I would add the first line (`>1`), then create a simple macro which yanks the numbered line, goes down one line, pastes the yank and increments the number. In vim normal-mode commands: <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd>. If you saved the macro to register `q`, execute it with <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>.

Assuming the first record is on the first line, you can do it with two invocations of GNU sed like this:

```
sed '=' file | sed 's/^[0-9]/>&/'
```

Or with `nl` which only numbers lines that contain data:

```
nl file | sed 's/^ *\([0-9]\+\)\t*/>\1\n/'
```

It can be done more intuitively with `awk`:

```
awk 'NF { print ">" ++i "\n" $0 }' file
```

Output in all cases:

```
>1
CTACGGTGTGCTCTTCCGATCTGACTATG
>2
AGTTGGTGTGCTCTCCCGATCTCGCTCCCTC
>3
GTGAGGTGTGCTCTTCCGATCTCCGGCAGTGTGCT
```

Answer (score 2):

To insert a line number plus a marker that will be used in the next command, you can use something like this:

```
:%s/^/\=printf('>%-d ', line('.'))
```

To insert a newline, replace something telltale with "\r". Something very simple such as this should do the job in this case

```
:'<,'>s/ /\r
```

There are a lot more vim tips at `http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_Tips_Wiki`